# Xamarin Studio не могу работать в консоли

Tags: c#, xamarin-studio

Добрый день!
Подскажите пожалуйста! Создаю простейшую программку, запускаю, но в открывшейся консоли не могу вводить значения, чтобы программа решала и выводила ответ. В самой консоли не печатаются цифры и буквы. В чем проблема?

```
using System;

namespace Test {
    class MainClass {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {

            double num;
            Console.WriteLine("How old are you?");
            num = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine ());

            if (num > 18.23d) 
                Console.WriteLine("You are older than 18.23");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А покажите код программы?

Comment: добавил в сам вопрос

Comment: Вы на маке что-ли работаете?

Comment: нет, на винде...

Comment: Я не уверен что Xamarin умеет собирать проекты для обычной консоли, он все таки на мобильные платформы ориентирован. Код, в общем-то корректный и должен работать, при правильной сборке проекта. В настройках проекта должно быть `Output type: Console Application`.

Comment: спасибо, попытаюсь сейчас!